# How can one retrieve rewards/penalties for a given validator address and eth1 block height?

Tags: eth-2.0, validators, beacon-chain, block-reward

I was left a bit confused after reading the docs [here](https://kb.beaconcha.in/rewards-and-penalties), [here](https://benjaminion.xyz/eth2-annotated-spec/phase0/beacon-chain/) and the [code here](https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/blob/3d3b9d1217c14a46c20edbd5adc9a91ddd690b0f/tools/specs-checker/data/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md) on the topic.

My key questions:

1. Is there a way to retrieve a certain validator's reward value for a given block via API responses only?
2. If so, then which API methods to use for the most effective result?

At the very moment, it seems to me that the only way to get such data is to calculate rewards using [Beacon API](https://ethereum.github.io/beacon-APIs/#/Node) data (beacon and config data endpoints in particular) and
[the formulas](https://kb.beaconcha.in/rewards-and-penalties). This gotta be a heck of a computation (assuming we need to know a sum of all validators' effective balances at a given moment in time), so I'm looking for some other way around.

There's a high probability of me missing something or overcomplicating, overthinking the problem. That's why I'd highly appreciate any kind of help or advice.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it's not possible.

You need something that will compute the rewards from the beginning like what [the beaconcha.in](https://github.com/gobitfly/eth2-beaconchain-explorer) indexing process is doing or maybe something like [chaind](https://github.com/wealdtech/chaind) is doing. In both cases, you need to setup your own clients on a machine, sync them and run that indexing process on top of it.